# How to recover drupal password in localhost?

Tags: 7, users

I have a complete Drupal website on localhost. I forgot the password and username for my account. I found the username in the database, but the password is hashed.

I can't send emails from localhost, so recovering the password using the email is not possible.

How can I recover the password?

Comment: @AjitS no that is not, I have it on localhost and I can't send email from that!

Comment: Well, if you configure a SMTP client you can. But that is a different story!

Comment: With drupal-7 you can do like this:http://goo.gl/zyQyzd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update the password via mysql. You can run the following query in mysql to update password. The given hashed value is the hashed value of password: NewPassword

```
UPDATE users SET pass = '$S$DRSUIz9NFfxOXKPveQ00UTGMzsJe62LjYvVHfYJ8I8wuy4zRqVBK' WHERE uid = 1;
```

For detailed instructions go through these article [Resetting the administrator password with sql-query (Drupal 7)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Gnu/Linux or compatible, the simplest method with *drush* is this:

[Install drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676) (if you haven't done so yet).

Go to your `drupal-root/sites/mysite` folder.

Type in the Gnu/Linux CLI:

```
sudo drush upwd --password="newpassword" admin
```

(where "admin" is the user name of user #1).

The password will now be "newpassword".

Alternatively, you can type in the Gnu/Linux CLI:

```
sudo drush uli
```

and use the URL it gives you to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux:

1. [Install drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676)
2. Go to your `drupal-root/sites/mysite` folder
3. Type `sudo drush uli` and use the URL it gives you to log in.

Comment: Thanks, But I am using Windows. +1 for u

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Drush you could do:

1. Edit your index.php in your Drupal site root
2. Insert the code below between "drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);" and "menu_execute_active_handler();":

   require_once 'includes/password.inc';
   echo user_hash_password('CHANGE_THIS_TO_DESIRED_PASSWORD');
   die();
3. Copy the hashed string
4. Go to your database administration UI or phpmyadmin
5. Go to the users table
6. Find the admin user (mostly is the user with 1 as the uid)
7. Update the admin's password field using the hashed string you just copied.
8. Comment or delete the code in step 2
9. Refresh your site and login

Comment: I tried this way but not working! each time that I refreshed the page the password that printed was changing

Comment: Ah! Just do it once and the string you replaced the CHANGE_THIS_TO_DESIRED_PASSWORD is the password you would use on login but hope your getting things sorted out already though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open the `users` table in *phpmyadmin*, in the password column, delete the content of the row of the admin username. In this way the password is deleted.

Open the database of another website in your localhost that you know the admin password, open the `users` table, in the password column, select the row of the admin user and copy its content to the admin row of `users` table of database of the website that you forget its password.

Notice that the passwords are saved in hash format in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file "new_password.php" (or with any other name) inside your drupal folder and access it using browser. It will generate one way encrypted hash password for you.

```
<?php
  define("DRUPAL_ROOT", getcwd());
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . "/includes/bootstrap.inc";
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
  require_once "includes/password.inc";
  echo user_hash_password("123456");
  die();
  menu_execute_active_handler();
?>
```

When you run this code in browser it will show you hash password like

```
$S$D95YW4EejaUDPq5nZ7Z2Ljx1Ud4wlN1iTMQdAKton70JcQpCZmrG
```

Now you need to update your database table using above hash. Open your database using PHPMyAdmin or Workbench and run the below query.

```
UPDATE users SET pass = '$S$D95YW4EejaUDPq5nZ7Z2Ljx1Ud4wlN1iTMQdAKton70JcQpCZmrG' WHERE uid = 1;
```

Now you can access drupal using username as "admin" and password as "123456". Make sure you update password after login to the admin.