# How do I find the lost administrator login credentials?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

How do I find the lost administrator login credentials? I have deployed locally an old Drupal 7 website and I can't find the administrator login credentials since Windows had crashed 3 years ago.

Comment: You can’t get the password, it’s one-way hashed. Use Drush’s `uli` command or similar to get yourself access, `upwd` to reset the password, and so on

Comment: thx, how to find the admin user name?

Comment: you can find users info in `users_field_data`  table .

Comment: The `users` table in Drupal 7.

Comment: Drush ULI and it won't matter. You can also change passwords with it.

Comment: thx, I will try and write the results

Comment: drush upwd --password- "123456" "user"
Command user-password needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more          [error]
functional Drupal environment to run this command.
The drush command 'upwd 123456 user' could not be executed.                                                      [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                     [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured

Comment: What to do with these errors? Thx

Comment: Use Drush or database approach as explained in: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210921/how-do-i-change-the-admin-password-form-phpmyadmin https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150866/how-to-recover-drupal-password-in-localhost